# React Native Scrollview: scroll to top on button click

Tags: react-native, native-base

So I have a component with `ScrollView` which contains many elements, so you have to scroll a long way down.

Now there should be a button at the bottom of the page that on click will scroll the page back to top.

I already created the button as a FAB (floating action button) in an extra component.

It is integrated in a parent component, where the `ScrollView` is located.

What I found was that you have to create a `ref` in the `ScrollView` component and implement a button right there that uses this `ref` to make scrolling work. Simplified, here is what I have so far:

```
imports ...
const ParentComponent: React.FC<Props> = () => {

  const scroll = React.createRef();

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView ref={scroll}>
        <SearchResult></SearchResult> // creates a very long list 
        <FloatingButton
          onPress={() => scroll.current.scrollTo(0)}></FloatingButton>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;
```

As you can see, there is the component `FloatingButton` with the `onPress()` method.

Here is the implementation:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Container, Content, Button, Icon, Fab} from 'native-base';

const FloatingButton: React.FC<Props> = () => {

  return (
    <Fab
      position="bottomRight"
      onPress={(???}>
      <Icon name="arrow-round-up" />
    </Fab>
  );
};

export default FloatingButton;
```

Now the problem: Where should I do the `onPress()` method? Because if I leave it in the parent component, it won't work because it is not directly located in the `Fab` (in `FloatingButton`). I would like to do the `onPress()` logic in `Fab`, but if I do so, the `ScrollView` that it needs is not available, because it's in the parent component. My idea was to maybe passing the `ref` as `prop` into `FloatingButton`, but for some reason this didn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could either let the parent hook into the `FloatingButton`'s `onPress` function or pass the `ref` down to the `FloatingButton` directly.

```js
export const Parent : FC<ParentProps> = props => {
    const scrollRef = useRef<ScrollView>();

    const onFabPress = () => {
        scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
            y : 0,
            animated : true
        });
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}>
                {/* Your content here */}
            </ScrollView>
            <FloatingButton onPress={onFabPress} />
        </View>  
    );
}

export const FloatingButton : FC<FloatingButtonProps> = props => {
    const { onPress } = props;

    const onFabPress = () => {
        // Do whatever logic you need to
        // ...

        onPress();
    }

    return (
        <Fab position="bottomRight" onPress={onFabPress}>
            <Icon name="arrow-round-up" />
        </Fab>
    );
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Works like a charm.

Comment: after over a 100 solutions, this is the only one that actually worked

Comment: spent so much time on this because auto complete was not showing anything like scrollTo. Worked in first try

Comment: Property 'scrollRef' doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You should determine the horizontal or vertical value you want to scroll to, like this code snippet.

```
onPress={()=> 
   this.scroll.current.scrollTo({ x:0, y:0 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my snack code. Hope it might be helpful for you.

```
https://snack.expo.io/@anurodhs2/restless-edamame
```

Comment: first of all, thanks a lot for your help. Your code works in my application. However, so far I used Functional Components and would like to stick with them. You used Class components in your example. Is it possible to do it in Functional components, too?